# Validating radiobuttons in android

Tags: android, radio-button

I know that you cant uncheck a radiobutton in android by pressing it again. But you can uncheck all the other radioButtons if one radiobutton is checked.

The question is how can I know that one radiobutton was clicked in a radiobutton group..?

could someone also give me a link to a short snippet of how to to reset all the radiobuttons in a group while one radio button was selected?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
radioButtonGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup,
            int radioButtonID) {
        switch(radioButtonID) {
            case R.id.radioButton1:
                //radio 1 clicked
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                //radio 2 clicked
                break;
            case R.id.radioButton3:
                //radio 3 clicked
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

I hope it wil help u..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html) (scroll down to Radio Buttons).

It reads: ***It's important that the RadioButtons are grouped together by the RadioGroup element so that no more than one can be selected at a time. This logic is automatically handled by the Android system. When one RadioButton within a group is selected, all others are automatically deselected.***

It also provides some code snippets for listening to and handling click events.